# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar un mensaje de advertencia en mi vista?

Tags: javascript, html

Quería saber como poder hacer para mostrar un mensaje de advertencia en mi vista. Mi proyecto esta siendo realizado en laravel-7 y en una de mis vistas tengo un formulario donde un campo es el resultado de una resta entre otros dos campos de tipo input.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
             <label for="costUSD">Costo total en USD-O</label>
             <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="costUSD" class="form-control" id="costUSD" onchange="Todas();" onkeyup="Todas();"   required>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="list_priceUSD">Precio Lista (USD-O)</label>
                <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="list_priceUSD" id="list_priceUSD" class="form-control"   onchange="Todas();" onkeyup="Todas();"  required>
</div>
```

Y esta es mi función de JS que calcula mi margen bruto:

```
function CalcularMarginUSD(){
    var listPrice = document.getElementById('list_priceUSD').value;
    console.log(list_priceUSD);
    var costUSD = document.getElementById('costUSD').value;
    console.log(costUSD);
    var marginUSDO = (listPrice - costUSD);
    document.getElementById('marginUSD').value = marginUSDO; 
}
```

Mi idea es poder hacer o una condicional o una función para que mientras el precio de lista sea mayor o igual a 0 (>=0) se bordee el input y muestre un mensaje de advertencia aclarando que el margen va a ser negativo, ya que margen bruto = costo en usd - precio de lista en usd. Pero que no sea un mensaje de error, es decir que me deje mandar el formulario igual pero que avise de la advertencia.

Comment: Voy a editar tu pregunta porqué cada repuesta varia dependiendo del lenguaje y framework, así que la solución que funciona con Laravel no va a funcionar con node.

Answer (score 1):

Todo eso que pides es facilmente alcanzable con JavaScript.

Por lo que veo estas usando Bootstrap. Por lo tanto, la forma en la que puedes mostrar la advertencia que pides es agregar un `<small>` debajo de el input de precio de lista y darle `display:none;color:red` para que el texto sea rojo y que no se muestre por defecto.

A partir de allí, puedes implementar un evento que se ejecute cada que un valor sea ingresado, y que compare si este es negativo; si es así, muestre el  mensaje en `<small>`; si no es así, oculte el `<small>`.

Quedaria algo así:

```js
function validar() {

  let precioLista = parseFloat(document.getElementById("list_priceUSD").value);

  if (precioLista <= 0) {
    // Como la clase ya esta agregada por defecto, la retiramos si precioLista <= 0;
    document.getElementById("error").classList.remove("d-none");
  } else {
    // Si precioLista > 0, quitamos la clase.
    document.getElementById("error").classList.add("d-none");
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="list_priceUSD">Precio Lista (USD-O)</label>
        <input type="number" step="00.01" name="list_priceUSD" id="list_priceUSD" class="form-control" onkeyup="validar()" required>
        <!-- .d-none es una clase de Bootstrap 4 que hace a un objeto invisible para el usuario y el layout -->
        <small id="error" class="d-none text-danger">Advertencia. El margen sera negativo.</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para más información:
Clase d-none: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Me esta devolviendo un empty string. Nose porque. Todos mis campos tienen el mismo id que en la funcion de javaScript.